# Graph API get all eligible roles for user

Tags: graph, microsoft-graph-api

I am having some difficulty getting a list of all eligible roles for a user using the Graph API. I am able to get assigned roles, but not eligible ones. The Uri I am using is below:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/roleManagement/directory/roleEligibilityScheduleRequests`

I have also tried using `beta`, instead of `v1.0`, but with no luck. This is the error message I am getting:

`Invoke-RestMethod: {"error":{"code":"UnknownError","message":"{\"errorCode\":\"PermissionScopeNotGranted\",\"message\":\"Authorization failed due to missing permission scope RoleEligibilitySchedule.ReadWrite.Directory,RoleManagement.ReadWrite.Directory.\",\"instanceAnnotations\":[]}","innerError":{"date":"2023-06-12T19:27:46","request-id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","client-request-id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}}}`

I have checked the API permissions in Azure AD and it definitely has those 2 permissions mentioned in the error message. Permissions were granted last week:

[image]

With PowerShell I have also tried `Get-MgRoleManagementDirectoryRoleEligibilityScheduleInstance`, with a similar error. Has anybody been able to get eligible roles in 365, with either this Uri or a different one?

At the request of a commenter, here is the PowerShell I am using in my API call attempts, including a successful call to prove the authentication works:

```
C:\> $Params = @{
>>     Uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$email"
>>     Headers = @{
>>         Authorization = "Bearer $Token"
>>         ConsistencyLevel = "eventual"
>>     }
>>     ErrorAction = 'Stop'
>> }
C:\> $User = (Invoke-RestMethod @Params)
C:\> $Params.Uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/roleManagement/directory/roleEligibilityScheduleRequests"
C:\> $Results = (Invoke-RestMethod @Params)
Invoke-RestMethod: {"error":{"code":"UnknownError","message":"{\"errorCode\":\"PermissionScopeNotGranted\",\"message\":\"Authorization failed due to missing permission scope RoleEligibilitySchedule.ReadWrite.Directory,RoleManagement.ReadWrite.Directory.\",\"instanceAnnotations\":[]}","innerError":{"date":"2023-06-13T13:22:35","request-id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx","client-request-id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}}}
C:\>
```

Comment: Tested from Graph Explorer with RoleEligibilitySchedule.ReadWrite.Directory and RoleManagement.ReadWrite.Directory delegated permissions and it works fine without any error. Maybe share a code how you connect to Graph API.

Comment: I just updated the question with the Powershell output. I also included a successful call to show the token is functioning